# Accessing, from inside a script, the exact command that was issued on terminal to fire the script in question

Tags: command-line, bash, history

Let's say I issue the following command:

```
./myscript.sh file* test.txt
```

Now, I wish `myscript.sh` to be able to create a variable, say `howiwasran`, such that if it were to `echo ${howiwasran}`, the output should be exactly what was typed on the command line,  apart from the script's path and name. So the output should just be:

```
file* test.txt
```

I know about noglobbing, and passing the arg inside quote and then using quotes inside the script too, but I wanted something which works at a deeper level.

I couldn't do it even using the history file, even when real time updating is set.

As of now the need is avoidable, but still I am curious.

Comment: Does `tail -n 2 <(history) | head -n -1` or `fc -nl -1` work for you?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: `history` isn't enabled in a non-interactive shell, `set -o history` enables it.

Comment: @bac0n not that ! OP needs history of the shell before the script started executing.

Comment: The shell that is executing the script will not have it, because the interactive shell will have performed all the expansions first before launching the script. So you'll have to rely on your users bash history configuration: that seems a very fragile expectation. I too wonder about your requirements.

Comment: Probably the only way is to configure the shell (via .profile or .bashrc files) so that every terminal session is being recorded using `script` utility or something similar, and then to pull the command from the logfile recorded by `script`. This would be quite complicated however.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to achieve. Knowing the exact command used (e.g. `./myscript file*`) is not very useful. You normally want to know what script was called (`./myscript.sh` is a relative path so it won't help if you're in another dir) and what arguments were passed to it (the script never saw `files*`, it only saw the _expansion_ of the _glob_ `files*`). If you explain what you are trying to achieve with this we can answer you better.

Comment: I understand that OP wants to know the verbatim command typed on the terminal, before any shell expansions etc. I don't understand why however.

Comment: "I couldn't do it even using the history file". That is because AFAIK the closest you can get a command saved to bash history is after it is done executing but the command you are trying to retrieve which is the current execution of your script **is still executing** ....Thus it is not in the history file yet at this moment. If you show us the purpose from this question!, maybe we can help.

Comment: @Raffa no, sorry. The history isn't even really relevant here since it behaves differently in scripts, but the command is written as soon as it is launched, and not after it has finished. Just try running `sleep 60 &`, which will run `sleep` for one minute in the background, and immediately running `history | tail`. You will see the `sleep` command listed there despite the fact that it is still running. The history _file_ is another thing entirely and commands will only be written there after the current shell exits (_not_ after the command itself finishes).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
howiwasran="${@: 2}"
```

In bash, `$@` is a bash array of arguments, including the script name (`$@` is similar to `argv` in C/C++).

The colon here is used to offset into the array. I include a space between the `:` and the `2` because an expression like

```
${var:-2}
```

has a different meaning:

> ${parameter:-word}
> Use Default Values. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

<sup>([source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash))</sup>

Therefore leaving a space between the `:` and the number ensures you can make negative offsets into the array, similarly to using negative array indices in python.

Note that this syntax is not valid in `sh`. If you use this syntax with `sh`, you will get a `Bad substitution` error.

Also note that something like `file*`, if unquoted, will be expanded by the shell with globbing. Globbing will be applied *before* the script is started, so the script will not see `file*` in its `$@`, it will see something like `file1 file2 file3 ...` instead.

Comment: Hmm. So basically i am asking for something fundamentally impossible.